# How to install additional libraries in Wolfram language's SystemModel?

Tags: system-modeler, system-modeling

I have been using a command like the following to get models into Wolfram language:

```
model=SystemModel["EducationExamples.Physics.GyroscopicPrecession.HelicopterModel"]
```

But now I need models that don't come in the standard package but are available for free in an external library. Since I don't have `SystemModeler` installed on the machine I can't use its GUI interface to install the library. So what is the Wolfram language way to install this library.

```
model=SystemModel["BioChem.Examples.MichaelisMenten"]
```

I have downloaded the file:

```
BioChem_1.3.1_MULT.sma
```

So where do I put it so Wolfram language detects it?

Comment: As an exmaple, the model "IntroductoryExamples.MultiDomain.DCMotor" can be found under: "...Math12.1\SystemFiles\Components\WSMCore\L\IntroductoryExamples\MultiDomain" as file "DCMotor.mo". Therefore I guess that your model should go somewhere close.

Comment: @DanielHuber but the downloaded file is a library file with extension `.sma` not `.mo` so this might not work.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a file for MMA? MMA help say<s that you need a file with extension ".mo".

Comment: `.sma` is a file format created by WRI in order to have a "flat" model file that includes all model dependencies (→[Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/SMA.html)). `Import` of such a file will give a `SystemModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System modeler libararies are aparently imported like follows:

```
Import[FileNameJoin[{...path to file...,"BioChem_1.3.1_MULT.sma"}],"SMA"];
```

Now this works:

```
model=SystemModel["BioChem.Examples.MichaelisMenten"]
```

If there is a better and more official way to import the system modeler libraries in WL, feel free to edit.